# How to detect last occurance in dom-repeat in polymer 2

Tags: polymer-2.x

I'm trying to add a block of HTML only after the last block inside a dom-repeat, however, it has to be right after the html blocks inside the dom-repeat, because if I put it outside the dom-repeat there'll be a dom-repeat block between the 2 blocks, something like angularJS's ng-class="{'last':$last}"

Answer (score 0):

You may check the index number if you are trying to set a HTML block just after the last item.

[Demo](https://codepen.io/cappittall/pen/PVrraa?editors=1011)

```
<template is="dom-repeat" items="[[users]]">
      <div>[[item]]</div>

     <!--This is the blok after last element in dome-repeat -->        
     <template is="dom-if" if="{{_isLastItem(index)}}">
            <div>This is just after last item</div>
      </template>
 </template>


class MyTest extends Polymer.Element {
  static get is() { return 'my-test'; }

  constructor(){
     super();

     // set ie. users array or import data from parent.
     this.set('users',['Kaan', 'Timur', 'Oğuz', 'Aybüke'])
  }
  _isLastItem(i){ 
      return i===this.users.length -1;
  }
```

Comment: This adds a dom-if block after each iteration, which negates the whole point, all I want is to make all of them siblings right after each other

Comment: Can you please explain what exactly you want. Why `dom-if` negates?

Comment: My whole problem was that the dom-repeat adds a block of html after it ends, now dom-if adds its own block as well